# how to result change in matrix form?

Tags: java

how to change result in matrix form?

what error in this code?

```java
package arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixAddition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Enter Dimension : ");
        int rows = sc.nextInt();
        int cols = sc.nextInt();
        
        int a[][] = new int[rows][cols];
        int b[][] = new int[rows][cols];
        
        System.out.println("Enter array a");
        for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
                a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter array b");
        for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
                b[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int c[][] = new int[rows][cols];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("result array c is: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
                System.out.print(c[i][j] +" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> Enter Dimension : 
> 2 3
> Enter array a
> 2 3 4
> 5 -2 -1
> Enter array b
> 7 8 9
> -5 -7 -5
> result array c is: 
> 9 11 13 0 -9 -6

Comment: Move your println statement up inside the i for loop.

Comment: where? i want to result in this form  9  11  13                                                                     .                                                         0  -9  -6

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. Do you want to output each row of your result array on a new line? Or should they be separated by a comma?

To print every row in a newline:

```
System.out.println("result array c is: ");
for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
        System.out.print(c[i][j] +" ");
    }
    // all columns of a row printed, begin a new line
    System.out.println();
}
```

To print a comma between rows:

```
System.out.println("result array c is: ");
for(int i = 0; i<rows;i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<cols ; j++) {
        System.out.print(c[i][j] +" ");
    }
    // all columns of a row printed, insert a comma
    System.out.print(", ");
}
```

If that's not the solution, please specify your question for more information.